# Cluster wind direction

Tags: clustering, multivariate-analysis

anyone can help me about how to cluster wind direction? i want to cluster wind in degrees 1-360 so i convert to x and y in cartesian just like this ...
is it okay ??
[image]

i measure (d), it is a distance between point (0,0) to poitn at circle
any suggestion??

Comment: Do you have a dataset you're trying to cluster? It's not clear what you're actually asking here

Comment: Clustering wind direction strikes me as unphysical for most stations. The exceptions would be where local conditions promote strong bimodality, e.g anabatic and katabatic winds, onshore and offshore winds.

Answer (score 1):

Use hierarchical clustering, and the difference in angle modulo 360. i.e.

```
dist(a,b) = min(abs(a-b),abs(a-(360-b)),abs((360-a)-b))
```

If you want to use Cartesian coordinates, center at 0, i.e. use

```
x, y = sin(a), cos(a)
```

Why would you use a circle that is not centered at 0?

Comment: Please check my edits preserve your meaning.

Comment: i have no idea about how to clouster wind direction, i have 30 years dataset in 425 grids, so make just like the picture, i measure a distance (d) which measure the distance between point (0,0) to the circle, the circle represent represent wind direction in 1-360 degrees, what do you think? im sorry i just newbie in clustering @NickCox